# Is there any way to export a file from Chrome's local storage?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, local-storage

So I have save file of an HTMl based game in Chrome's local storage,which I can easily find in Application bar in developer tools. So is there any way to export that file from local storage?